# Having an error while trying to conditionally read a file in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I receive datafiles with a specific column layout, but sometimes I receive them as .csv, sometimes as .xls, sometimes as .xlsx. A sample datafile, greatly simplified, is at the end of the question.

I want to read the file into R with a single command, so I wrote this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)

thePath <- 'sample.csv'
x <- ifelse(grepl('.*\\.csv', thePath), 
            read_csv(thePath), 
            read_excel(thePath, sheet = 1))
```

This sends back the first column of the file only, as a list that contains only text, no numbers:

```
x
[[1]]
 [1] "# Some Title Text"                                                  
 "#================================================================="
 [3] NA                                                                   
 NA                                                                  
 [5] "##############################################"                     
 "# Some Header text"                                                
 [7] "##############################################"                     
 NA                                                                 
 [9] "Group1"                                                             
 "Group2"                                                            
 [11] "Group3"
```

But, when I run this...

```
grepl('.*\\.csv', thePath)
[1] TRUE
read_csv(thePath)
```

...it returns a data frame I can work with (I would have to remove the headers and whitespace, but that's easy to do in R).

So my regular expression returns `TRUE` like I want it to, and my `read_csv` command is not wrong, but combining them together in the `ifelse` statement is causing something to break. Can someone tell me why this is happening and what the fix to my `ifelse` command should be?

Sample comma-separated data:

```
#=================================================================,
# Some Title Text,
#=================================================================,
,
,
##############################################,
# Some Header text,
##############################################,
,V1
Group1,22345
Group2,21341
Group3,45678
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `if/else` instead of `ifelse`

```
x <- if(grepl('.*\\.csv', thePath)) {
        read_csv(thePath)
         } else {read_excel(thePath, sheet = 1)
    }
```

Comment: @mmyoung77 the `test`, `yes`, `no`  are assumed to be of the same length.  Here, the yes, no are of different classes i.e. data.frame/tbl_df.  You may need to wrap with `list`

Comment: @mmyoung77 I wouldn't use `ifelse` even if the length is greater than 1  i.e. you have multiple elements in thePath'.  Instead loop over thePath, and apply if/else